# TEMP files encrypted on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, encryption, privacy

I am going to sell my iPhone soon and wondered as to the safety of the temp files/cache files on iPhone for apps like twitter,Reddit,WhatsApp ETC.

I am aware that iPhone has File based encryption and was just curious as to whether that included the temp/cache files on the system?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260901/is-data-stored-in-iphone-encrypted-by-default?rq=1

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the prompt response, I’m a bit paranoid due to past experiences and was just curious as to whether it would be reasonable to assume that therefore cache/TEMP files would also be encrypted ? Thanks

Comment: All data is encrypted (and will not be accessible any longer once the encryption key gets deleted when the device is erased).

Comment: When @nohillside says "ALL DATA" they mean it. The Secure Enclave ensures all storage and the keys get destroyed for decryption

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a support article about [what to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351):

- Unpair Apple Watch
- Log out of iCloud/iTunes Store
- Deregister iMessage if this is your only/last Apple device
- Erase device

This will ensure that all data on the device gets removed, and that the new owner can get access to it.